# Definition of standard-layout class in C++14

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer

A *standard-layout* class is defined in [class]/7 in C++14, as follows (emphasis is mine):

A *standard-layout* class is a class that:

- (7.1) — has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout
  class (or array of such types) or reference,
- (7.2) — has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes
  (10.1),
- (7.3) — has the same access control (Clause 11) for all non-static
  data members,
- (7.4) — has no non-standard-layout base classes,
- (7.5) — either has no non-static data members in the most derived
  class **and** at most one base class with non-static data members, or has
  no base classes with non-static data members, and
- (7.6) — has no base classes of the same type as the first non-static
  data member.

My concern is in relation to bullet (7.5): how is it possible to have **no** non-static data members in the most derived class and at the same time having one base class with non-static data members?

In other words, aren't the non-static data members of the base class, also non-static data members of the most-derived class?

Comment: Think of objects as the russian matruska dolls. The most derived object is the outer shell of the doll. While the most base object is at its core.

Comment: In the end though, they are different dolls.

Comment: Do you mean Matryoshka doll?

Comment: @bipll Yeap that ones :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is a defect in C++14, specifically [CWG 1813](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1813).  Although it can be repaired by reading "non-static data members" to refer only to *direct* (non-inherited) non-static data members (as is probably necessary elsewhere), the chosen fix has been to replace the language you found problematic with the following:

> A standard-layout class is a class that: [...]
>
> - has all non-static data members and bit-fields in the class and its base classes first declared in the same class, [...]

This is a little tricky to get right; there is some resistance to the idea of considering inherited members as members of the derived class, even though **[class.derived]** has:

> [...] Unless redeclared in the derived class, members of a base class
> are also considered to be members of the derived class. Members of a base class other than constructors are said to be *inherited* by the derived class. [...]

Notwithstanding this, a number of places where both direct and inherited non-static data members are intended to be considered specifically call out inherited data members, for example also in **[class]** (after the resolution to [CWG 1672](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1672)):

> 8.6 - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or nonstatic data members (including, recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate or contained union),

Or in **[basic.lval]**:

> 7.8 - If X is a non-union class type, the set M(X) is empty if X has no (possibly inherited (Clause 10))
> non-static data members; [...]

Meanwhile, in many places "members" has to be read as referring only to direct members to make sense; to begin with and only looking at non-static data members (not member functions), [expr.rel]/3.2, [expr.const]/5.1, [dcl.constexpr]/4.6, [class.mem]/17, /19, [special]/5, [class.ctor]/4.3, /4.4, /4.10, /4.12, [class.dtor]/5.6, [class.base.init]/2, /13.3, [class.copy]/12.2, /12.4, /18.2, /25.2, /25.4, /26.3, /27, [except.spec]/15.1.1.1, /15.2, /15.3 are all places where "non-static data members" could or should have "direct" prefixed.

On the other hand, in some places (e.g. in the amended [class], or in [class.copy]/23.2-23.3, /28) "members" is implicitly taken to include inherited members, so it's a bit of a mess.

Comment: `No, non-static data members of a base class are not considered to be non-static data members of the derived class.` Is there a specific quote for this in the Standard?

Comment: `7.8 - If X is a non-union class type, the set M(X) is empty if X has no (possibly inherited (Clause 10)) non-static data members;` I couldn't find this in C++14.

Comment: @Alexander that's [CWG 1672](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1672).

Comment: I'm looking forward to your post in c++ std-discussion. Thanks.

Comment: @Alexander I've done my best: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/PM4TMJzD0tM/y5JJWG6_CAAJ

Comment: Congrats. That was a great answer (+1)