# What is the purpose of bullet point (7.5) in [class]/7, in C++14?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer

This is basically a continuation of [my prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39904101/definition-of-standard-layout-class-in-c14).

This is [class]/7 in C++14:

A standard-layout class is a class that:

- (7.1) — has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or reference,
- (7.2) — has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1),
- (7.3) — has the same access control (Clause 11) for all non-static data members,
- (7.4) — has no non-standard-layout base classes,
- (7.5) — either has no non-static data members in the most derived class and at most one base class with
  non-static data members, or has no base classes with non-static data members, and
- (7.6) — has no base classes of the same type as the first non-static data member.

Consider the following snippet:

```
struct B{ int i; };
struct A : B{ int j; };
```

`A` satisfies bullet points (7.1) thru (7.4), but doesn't satisfy (7.5), as `A` has a non-static data member and has a base class with a non-static data member.

What is the problem with `A` being a standard-layout class?

**Edit**

As far as I can understand the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7166667/5479741) to the question of which this is being considered a dupe, the snippet above would have undefined behavior, if I tried to cast a pointer to `A` to the first data member of the base class `B` and back, because of this sentence written by the OP:

`Within a class, members are allocated in increasing addresses according to the declaration order. However C++ doesn't dictate the order of allocation for data members across classes.`

But that doesn't seem to answer my question. Suppose for example that in a certain compiler implementation, base `B` would follow `struct A` in memory, instead of preceding it. But this would contradict the fact that there is an implicit conversion, from a pointer to a derived class, to a pointer to a base class, according to [conv.ptr]/3:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv D”, where D is a class type, can be
>   converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv B”, where B is a base
>   class (Clause 10) of D.

That is, if the base `B` followed `struct A` in memory, the above implicit conversion would be invalid.

Comment: Why would the conversion be invalid? The conversion would just make the appropriate offset and give you the right pointer.

Comment: @Barry [conv.ptr]/3 does not say anything about an offset. Otherwise, if what you were correct, this would be possible: `A a; A* p = &a; B* q = p;` with `q != p`, i.e., a copy initialization, where the target `q` has a different value than the source `p`.

Comment: That's definitely possible. Consider a class with two non-empty bases where you cast a pointer to the derived class to a pointer to the 2nd base.

Comment: @Barry You convinced me and also answered my question. Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 2):

There are two important guarantees that the standard provides for standard-layout structs:

1. The first non-static data member, in declaration order, or a standard-layout struct is at offset 0 ([[class.mem.general]/27](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem.general#27)).
2. It is possible to define the *common initial sequence* of two such structs, which is obtained by comparing the members of each struct in declaration order; see [[class.mem.general]/23](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem.general#23). And when a union contains two or more members whose types are (potentially different) standard-layout structs, there is a limited form of legal type punning between them, as long as you only read from the common initial sequence; see [[class.mem.general]/26](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem.general#26).

Both of these guarantees rely on the fact that in a standard-layout struct, there is no ambiguity as to which non-static data member is "first". That first non-static data member is located at offset 0, and when comparing this standard-layout struct to another one, it will be compared with the first non-static data member of the other struct to determine whether they belong to the common initial sequence.

If the standard were relaxed to allow class `A` in your example to be standard-layout, it would have to explain which member is first. As discussed in the comments, implementations have freedom to lay out `i` before `j` or `j` before `i`. In order to make `A` standard-layout, the standard would have to take away that freedom from implementations.

Only in the special case where all non-static data members are first declared in the same class, it was judged worthwhile to require all implementations to lay out the class as if all non-static data members were first declared in the most derived class, and all base classes take up no space.

Answer (score 0):

Directly answering the question as phrased:

The purpose of this bullet is to *allow* very simple cases of inheritance where only *one* of the classes has data members.

Data layout for inheritance is unspecified, so the standard could just disallow inheritance altogether, but the standard makes an exception if one class has *no* data to treat the result still as Standard Layout.